# Missing reputation

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

Unsure if this should be asked here or some other SE, but I couldn't find any reference to this in the Help Centre.

[This answer](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/247399/in-the-rainshadow-of-an-equatorial-mountain-would-savanna-aw-or-hot-desert-b/247406#247406) posted to the WB stack shows 0 reputation, but I was notified via the Achievement menu—and it still shows this a week later—a +8 change to reputation.

There are no other recent adjustments that would explain it, such as hitting the 200/day reputation change, or a deleted user, or deleted question.

[image: Screenshot of answer and menu showing reputation]

Any idea what's happened?

(I gather there's something going on with moderators across the network, but I'd assume this is automated and nothing something moderators approve manually.)

Comment: you can click on the 0 to see the number of upvotes and downvotes you have. you should check out the privilege list

Answer (score 6):

### You had one upvote...

> Upvotes on an answer give the answerer +10 reputation.
> <sup>[From the help-center : Voting up](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)</sup>

So you got 10 points...

### ...And one downvote

> Downvotes remove 2 reputation from the post owner.<sup>[From the help-center : Voting down](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down)</sup>

But lost 2 points because of a downvote. This gets aggregated into a single value in your notification feed, ie. +8 points in total.

Note you can [get an overview of the upvotes and downvotes by clicking right on the score of the post](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), between the upvote and downvote buttons :

[image: Screenshot showing individual up and downvotes]